# returning results from a function to cells with offset

Tags: excel, vba

I'm learning and writing Excel VBA functions for my needs, and I'm stuck (pretty sure its easy, but I couldn't figure out the error, as excel only returns #VALUE as an error message)
I have written a vba function to return some data, and all is fine until the end. I have the results in a collection (chosen) but I cannot make the function write the results to cells in the same row. ı'm trying to use the range.offset within a for loop:

```
For t = 1 To chosen.Count
Application.Caller.Offset(0, t).Value = chosen(t)
Next t
```

so for 1, I want the value from chosen(1) to be returned to the cell on the right, same row. then for 2, it will go the the second cell on the right etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UDF or User Defined Function used as a formula cannot effect the value of another cell.

Now if you want to put an array of values in a range then you simply select the cells for the output and confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Using this function that returns an array:

```
Function myArr() As Variant()
myArr = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
End Function
```

I select A1:I1 with A1 active.

[image]

Then I enter

```
=myArr()
```

in the formula bar and hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter.  Excel will put the formula in all nine cells and put `{}` around the formulas. The array will then be put in those nine cells.

[image]

Comment: I have a collection instead of an array, does it matter? when I end the function with `myArr = chosen` or `myArr = chosen()` I get the error #VALUE.

Comment: Pushed the collection into an array and it worked. Thanks anyway.